# Comannd not executing in discord.js V14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Im making command what will insert different values based on your roles in discord server. But my command is not executing, any others yes. If I type that command to chat it'll reply appliaction not answering and wont type anything to console.

My command file: (uplatnitrole.js)

```
//Importovani discord.js balicku do kodu
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');

var db = require('../nastaveni/db.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'uplatnitrole',
    description: "Přidá role které máš na discordu na web!",
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('uplatnitrole')
        .setDescription('Přidá role které máš na discordu na web!'),

    //Spusteni scriptu pri interakci
    async execute(interaction) {
        console.log("tvojemam")
        const config = require('./../nastaveni/nastaveni.json');
        const policerole = config.POLICIE_ROLE_ID
        const admin = config.ATEAM_ROLE_ID
        const hzsrole = config.HZS_ROLE_ID
        const zzs = config.ZZS_ROLE_ID
        const dispecink = config.DISPECINK_ROLE_ID
        var webid
        var policajt
        var hzst
        var zzst
        var admint
        var dispect
        db.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE discordid = " + interaction.user.id, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
                interaction.reply({content: "Byl problém s databází", ephemeral: true})
                return
            }
            if (result[0] == undefined) {
                interaction.reply({content: "Nemáte účet na webu přiřazený k vašemu discordu. Zaregistrujte se na našem webu. URL najdete v informacích", ephemeral: true})
                return
            }
            webid = result[0].id
        })
        console.log(webid)
        if (interaction.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.id === policerole)) {
            db.query("INSERT INTO user" + webid + " (path, name, data1) VALUES ('user-profile', 'group', 'pcr')", function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                    interaction.reply({content: "Byl problém s databází", ephemeral: true})
                    return
                }
            })
            policajt = "PČR,"
        }

        if (interaction.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.id === hzsrole)) {
            db.query("INSERT INTO user" + webid + " (path, name, data1) VALUES ('user-profile', 'group', 'hzs')", function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                    interaction.reply({content: "Byl problém s databází", ephemeral: true})
                    return
                }
            })
            hzst = "HZS,"
        }

        if (interaction.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.id === zzs)) {
            db.query("INSERT INTO user" + webid + " (path, name, data1) VALUES ('user-profile', 'group', 'zzs')", function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                    interaction.reply({content: "Byl problém s databází", ephemeral: true})
                    return
                }
            })
            zzst = "ZZS,"
        }

        if (interaction.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.id === admin)) {
            db.query("INSERT INTO user" + webid + " (path, name, data1) VALUES ('user-profile', 'group', 'admin')", function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                    interaction.reply({content: "Byl problém s databází", ephemeral: true})
                    return
                }
            })
            admint = "Admin,"
        }

        if (interaction.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.id === dispecink)) {
            db.query("INSERT INTO user" + webid + " (path, name, data1) VALUES ('user-profile', 'group', 'dispecink')", function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    interaction.reply({content: "Byl problém s databází", ephemeral: true})
                    return
                }
            })
            dispect = "Dispečink"
        }

        interaction.reply({content: "Úspěšně jsme vám na webu přidali permise pro tyto role: " + policajt + " "+ hzst + " "+ zzst + " "+ admint + " "+ dispect + ". \n\*\*PRO TO ABY SE VÁM ROLE PŘIDALI SE NA WEBU PŘIHLAŠTE A ODHLAŠTE\*\*\n\*\*PRO TO ABY SE VÁM ROLE PŘIDALI SE NA WEBU PŘIHLAŠTE A ODHLAŠTE\*\*\n\*\*PRO TO ABY SE VÁM ROLE PŘIDALI SE NA WEBU PŘIHLAŠTE A ODHLAŠTE\*\*\n\*\*PRO TO ABY SE VÁM ROLE PŘIDALI SE NA WEBU PŘIHLAŠTE A ODHLAŠTE\*\*\n\*\*PRO TO ABY SE VÁM ROLE PŘIDALI SE NA WEBU PŘIHLAŠTE A ODHLAŠTE\*\*", ephemeral: true})
    }
}
```

Piece that executing interaction of mine main file (index.js):

```
//----------COMANNDY---------

//Hledání cesty
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
    const command = require(filePath);
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
}

//Spuštění comanndu
client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async interaction => {
    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) return;

    try {
        await command.execute(interaction);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        await interaction.reply({ content: 'Byl tu error při dělání commandu!', ephemeral: true });
    }
});
```